# Orchard CMS Update/Regenerate Permalinks after autoroute update

Tags: orchardcms, permalinks, bulk, orchardcms-1.8

I had no choice and needed to change a production site **autoroute** link for a certain **Content Type** and now i need to regenerate all the content **permalinks** for that specific type.

There are about 100 items in the content list.

is there a way to force **bulk regenerate** for all the contents?
maybe command line? or a module?

I'm using Orchard 1.8.1

Thanks!

Comment: You can set 'Automatically generate autoroute' on the content type. Then you might be able to just trigger a bulk update through migrations I guess.

Comment: Thanks, But i can read the instructions in orchard Autoroute field...
what is the best way to do it through migrations?
I tried and couldn't find a command line and wanted to avoid writing a module that does that.